# Angular Form Submission to update User Details - failing

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

**OBJECTIVE**

Form submission should update User details. Website should display user details while user types in information. Please note that "novalidate" is on and the "email" input is required (therefore the user.email information will only appear when a proper email has been submitted).

**LIVE DEMO**

http://plnkr.co/edit/z9ActiAn7sAIeY83xkxO?p=preview

### **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="formExample">

<head>
  <title>Anna Dowlin</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="SubmitCtrl">
    <p>Insert Email Below and watch User information be updated</p>
    <form novalidate>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" ng-model="user.email" required>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="submit(user)">
    </form>
  </div>
  <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

### **app.js**

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('formExample', []);

  app.controller('SubmitCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.submit = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

    }
  ]);
});
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. I am unsure where I am going wrong here. As you can see from the LIVE DEMO (http://plnkr.co/edit/z9ActiAn7sAIeY83xkxO?p=preview) the preview isn't rendering "{{user | json}}.
   [image: {{user | json}} not rendering]
2. If I place app.js into a  tag in the HTML and remove "... var app =" then the {{user | json}} disappears (but doesn't fully render). Why is this?
   [image: {{user | json}} partial render?]

Comment: Ah i see the answer worked for you below. Great!

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Please see Jacob Buczarski's response - the problem is due to the fact that <prev> isn't contained within <div> (where the controller lives). 


With regards to plunker, check to see if you have any browser extensions that are interferring with Plunker's operations

Comment: yep, saw that it worked for you, would also like to say i didn't downvote him either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your preview sits outside of your div with your ng-controller. Try moving it into the div.

Comment: This solution works and thank you for addressing and fixing a simple issue (it was driving me insane)!

The preview has to be within the <div> that the controller is called, otherwise it cannot fetch the user information.


P.S - I was not the one who downvoted you previously.